# Getting [not set] in Google Analytics only in one view

Tags: google-analytics

Thanks in advance,

I'm trying to fix the `not set` value in the google analytics google ads report.
I followed some of the posts around the web and `stack-overflow`, but with no luck.
 the funny thing is that the `not set` is only appearing in the `Master-view` in google analytics. 
I have 3 views:

1. All website Data
2. Master
3. Test

in the `All website data` all is working great. Iv tried to see if some of the settings are not the same, but couldn't find the reason. 
any Idea why this is happening

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set link from Google Ads to that view in Google Analytics Property settings (for your Ads Account ID listed).
In this moment only 'All website data' is linked.

Comment: Amazing man thank you so much I now see the settings you are a magician :)